# Outer Join Giving Fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a two table `table_a` and `table_b` , table_a has a field `a` and table_b has a field `b`.

```
a  b 
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
```

I have been written below sql & php code

```
$query  =  "select * from table_a FULL OUTER JOIN table_b on table_a.a = table_b.b";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   //this is 38 number line
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($row);
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

It's giving me below error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql\index.php on line 38
```

I am not finding any error here. If I use inner join here it's showing me result correctly.

Comment: call [mysqli_error](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp) to see if there are problems with your statment

Comment: If I use inner join it's showing result without any error. Problem only in full outer join.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  What results do you actually want to produce?

Comment: I want to produce
a = > [1,2,3,4,null,null]   b=>[null,null,3,4,5,6]

Comment: You have to use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and combine the results using `UNION ALL`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/3647441

Comment: @mapek, did you want to suggest that as an answer to help people searching for "outer join errors"?